# Is there a way to catch or detect if any of this PowerBI Button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am working on PowerBI Embedding and I have to detect if the 'include' or 'exclude' button has been selected.

[image]

I have tried using its html title, but it doesn't work:

```
    $("button[title='Include']").click(function () {
        alert("TEst");
    });

    $("button[title='Include']").on("click", function () {
        alert("TEst");
    });
```

I also tried PowerBI command trigger event but it didn't work as well:

```
report.on("commandTriggered", function (event) {
    let commandName = event.detail.command;
    if (commandName === "command name") {
        // Handler code
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no method to do that. The embedding does not have any event handlers that handle this Event. You can obtain detailed information about what visual was selected and if the Include or Exclude button was hit by just looking at the filters that have been set . This might not always work as user can pass filters at the time of embedding as well.